# Android Foreground Service - Trigger action after set time

Tags: android, timer, background, foreground-service

I'm working on a Wear OS app that mainly runs as a Foreground service, telling the user to "run" or "walk" at certain times. It can trigger these prompts from every 5 seconds to possibly after a few minutes.

I've used a Timer and Handler to schedule these actions, but they don't trigger reliably. I'm guessing this is due to background restrictions, although I'm running this as a foreground service.

Is there a proper way to trigger actions at set times from a foreground service?

Comment: This is a usecase for JobScheduler.  It shouldn't be using a ForegroundService at all.  JobScheduler allows you to tell the OS to wake up your app at a certain time, whether it's running or not.  This means you don't need to use the resources of a service.